# How to Google Maps setCenter / setZoom and set boundaries to include all markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been trying to figure this out from other posts, and can't quite grasp it.  Here is the code I'm working with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mapOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(29.4814305, -98.5144044),
  zoom: 10
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
    mapOptions);

var markers = [];

// Add a marker to the map and push to the array.
function addMarker(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
  });

  markers.push(marker);
}

// Sets the map on all markers in the array.
function setAllMap(map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
  }
}

// Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
function clearMarkers() {
  setAllMap(null);
}

// Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
function deleteMarkers() {
  clearMarkers();
  markers = [];
}

$('#ajax-form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formValues = $(this).serialize();
    //console.log('formValues: ' + formValues);

    // Clear previous results if present
    $('#results-list').html('');

    // Send Ajax Request 
    $.ajax({
        url: "/search",
        type: "POST",
        data: formValues,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            // console.log(data);
            var count = 0;

            $(data).each(function() {
                count++;
                // console.log('=========');
                // console.log('Id: ' + this.id);
                // console.log('Breed: ' + this.breed.name);
                // console.log('Dog Name: ' + this.name);
                // console.log('Sex: ' + this.sex);
                // console.log('Age: ' + this.age);
                // console.log('Purebred? ' + this.purebred);
                // console.log('Owner: ' + this.user.username);
                // console.log('=========');
                // console.log(this.user.fullAddress);

                // additional syntax to update html with search results.
                $('#results-list').append(
                    '<div class="row">' +
                        '<div class="col-md-2">' +
                            "<img src=\"" + this.img_path + "\" class=\"img-responsive thumbnail\" >" + 
                        '</div>' +

                        '<div class="zero-margin-left blog-block">' +
                            '<div class="col-md-6">' +
                                '<a href="http://ruff-love.com/dogs/' + this.id + '"><h3>' + this.name + '</a> | ' + '<a href="http://ruff-love.com/users/' + this.user.id + '">' + this.user.username + '</h3></a>' +
                                '</div>' + 
                                '</div>'
                    );

                var address = this.user.fullAddress;
                // console.log(address);

                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(result, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var latLngObj = result[0]["geometry"]["location"];
                        // add marker to array
                        addMarker(latLngObj);
                    } // endif

                    // COMMENTED OUT NON-WORKING CODE
                    // // map: an instance of GMap3
                    // // latlng: an array of instances of GLatLng
                    // var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                    // markers.each(function(n){
                    //    latlngbounds.extend(n);
                    // });
                    // map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
                    // map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

                }); // end geocode address

            }); // end each data loop

            // Clear previous markers
            deleteMarkers();

            // Add all markers to map
            setAllMap(map);
            // setAllMapTimed(map);

        } // end data function
    }); // end .ajax

}); // end ajax-form block
</script>
```

The whole point of this view is to provide search results, and plot markers on the map, according to a predefined radius (a distance within a specified zip code) and some other criteria.

I am trying to, upon marker array population, **set the boundaries of the map to include those markers and set the zoom at some kind of appropriate level**.

I understand what needs to be done with the boundaries, just not where exactly that code should go.  I have no idea how I would calculate zoom (a function to look at the overall distance included in boundaries and calculate zoom accordingly?).

I'm still learning javascript, so any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you're making an AJAX post to get some data.  You then loop over the data, calling your `addMarker` function for each, and add each marker into an array.  After the loop you then delete all markers from the array, then you try to add all the markers from the (now empty) array onto the map using your `setAllMap` function.

Firstly, when you initially create the markers, you're setting the map already in the MarkerOptions properties:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
```

So you shouldn't need to do this again in:

```
markers[i].setMap(map);
```

Secondly, I'd say do your call to `deleteMarkers` at the very start of your success handler, before you loop over the results of your AJAX request.

Finally, and to answer your question.  When you add each marker, you need to extend the map's "bounds" to include the marker.

Create a variable that is an empty bounds object like so:

```
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
```

You'll probably need to make this a global variable in the same way as your map and markers are.

Then in your addMarker function, add:

```
bounds.extend(location);
```

Finally at the end of the loop you want to apply this bounds to the map itself:

```
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Putting it altogether, something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mapOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(29.4814305, -98.5144044),
  zoom: 10
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
    mapOptions);

var markers = [];
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

// Add a marker to the map and push to the array.
function addMarker(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
  });

  markers.push(marker);

  bounds.extend(location);
}

// Sets the map on all markers in the array.
function setAllMap(map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
  }
}

// Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
function clearMarkers() {
  setAllMap(null);
}

// Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
function deleteMarkers() {
  clearMarkers();
  markers = [];
}

$('#ajax-form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formValues = $(this).serialize();

    // Clear previous results if present
    $('#results-list').html('');

    // Send Ajax Request 
    $.ajax({
        url: "/search",
        type: "POST",
        data: formValues,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            // Clear previous markers
            deleteMarkers();

            $(data).each(function() {
                // additional syntax to update html with search results.
                $('#results-list').append('...');

                var address = this.user.fullAddress;

                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(result, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var latLngObj = result[0]["geometry"]["location"];
                        // add marker to array
                        addMarker(latLngObj);
                    } // endif
                }); // end geocode address
            }); // end each data loop

            map.fitBounds(bounds);

        } // end data function
    }); // end .ajax

}); // end ajax-form block
</script>
```

Comment: I haven't yet had time to run through this, but will later today.  Thank you sincerely for taking the time to break this down.